# Automatically Align and Fill with a Char, on Text in Powershell

Tags: powershell, alignment, title

According to the text length in the variable, I can fill it with a character that I specify for the top and bottom lines.

**Sample Variables**

```
$mychar = "#"
$var1 = "Hello"
$var2 = "...Long Title..."
$var3 = "Some New Adventure"
$var4 = "Some New Adventure EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED"
```

**Expecting Output**

```
##########################################################################
########################### Some New Adventure ###########################

##########################################################################
############################ ...Long Title... ############################

##########################################################################???????
##################################### Hello #####################################

##########################################################################???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
##################################### Some New Adventure EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED EXCEED #####################################
```

**NOTICE:** The characters on the right and left of the text should be distributed in the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this function might accomplish what you're after:

```bash
function dostuff {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $InputString,
        [char] $Char = '#',
        [int] $BarLength = 74 # it seems?
    )

    $len = $BarLength / 2 - $InputString.Length / 2
    $Char.ToString() * $BarLength
    ' '.PadLeft([Math]::Floor($len), $Char) + $InputString + ' '.PadRight([Math]::Ceiling($len), $Char)
}

dostuff 'Hello'
dostuff '...Long Title...'
dostuff 'Some New Adventure'
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I approached the solution, there is only one point left, if the string length exceeds my bar length I get an error, can I increase the two with the same string length dynamically?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I added the `-BarLength` parameter because of that, so you can increment it as needed, i.e. `dostuff 'Hello' -BarLength 100`

Comment: There is only one bug I think, for example, try `dostuff 'asd' 16`, in this case, right and left is not equal size, left side is 34, right side is 35, so can we make it same length on the both side?,

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki How would the math look for that you're asking :)? Should we display half a `#` on each side? Even in your own "expected output" in the `hello` line you have 33 on the left and 34 on the right

Comment: You are right, I have a mistake too, I said it wrong when asking questions, what you did is very nice, it should be distributed exactly as half equal parts, I am correcting my question now, thanks

Comment: Ok, no problem, I made this, thank u again :)